# Onesignal using rest api

Tags: ionic2, postman, onesignal

i am using ionic 2 with pushnotifications.

i installed this plugin.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
  $ npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal
```

i am using create notification using postman

I refer to [OneSignal documentation: Using Postman](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/using-postman)

But i am getting this err

```
 "errors": [
        "app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."
    ]
```

I also put app_id and restAPIkey.

How can i fix this err.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the type of the body "application/json". 
In Postman, click body > raw > Click "Text" and change it to "application/json"
[Postman Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwjBI.png)